# Can I setup a pipeline stage to wait for a stage to complete on a separate pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I am working with 3 pipes based off 3 different repos within Azure DevOps. All 3 pipes deploy to the same cloud VM and all 3 have a set of E2E automated tests which are run after the deployment stage. I am currently having issues where 1 pull request is completed kicking off a deployment, then while the E2E tests are running a different pipe is kicked off, this causes services to stop on the VM during deployment making the E2E tests fail unusually.

Can I setup my pipe to only start a deployment + test if no other builds are already running against the target VM?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If these stages in release pipeline are set to run one after another, there will be no issues.
[image]

However, new push will trigger a new release and break the ongoing deployment, we suggest that you review this doc: [Release gates and approvals overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/?view=azure-devops), so you can try to set up [release deployment control using gates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/gates?view=azure-devops) or [define approvals and checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass).

Comment: Hi Lee Thomas, Does my answer work? Please check it and kindly let me know the result.